# how to hover using css?

Tags: css, hover

I am using Stacey, old portfolio supports which allow to build your website through your mac folders. I find it very convenient for what i wanted to achieve. I am now trying to modify its layout through html, Css code, been succesful on few stuff but get stuck on this point.
I want to hover image which is a link with text which is also a link to the same position.

html:

```
foreach $root do
  if $children do
    <p class="category col two"><em>@title</em></p>
    <ul class="project-list col seven">
    foreach $children do
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnail col two">
                <a href="@url"><img src="@thumb" alt=""></a>

            </div>
            <div class="summary col two">
                <a href="@url">
                <p>@title</p>
                <p><em>@date</em></p>
                <p><em class="background">&ndash; @keywords</em></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    endforeach
    </ul>
  endif
endforeach
```

css:

```
ul.project-list div.thumbnail a { border: 0px; }


ul.project-list div.summary{ 
height:140px; 
margin: 0px 0px 0px -140px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); 
visibility:hidden;
}
ul.project-list div.summary p  {text-align: center; }
ul.project-list div.thumbnail {display:block;}
ul.project-list div.thumbnail:hover  ul.project-list div.summary {visibility: visible;}
```

It is only a part of all code, @ link image to folders in mac...
Many thx if you are bothered.

S

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ul.project-list div.thumbnail:hover  ul.project-list div.summary {visibility: visible;}
```

to

```
ul.project-list div.thumbnail:hover + div.summary {visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works but it is now blinking... I am trying out to stop it if you have any suggestion....

Comment: @Staceyuser if you mean that it blinks once you hover the summary it is normal, since we only target the image for hovering. You should better use the `li`. So try `ul.project-list > li:hover div.summary {visibility: visible;}`

Comment: Very cool, thx gaby. my last issue is that once the thumbnail is hovered, the link only works on text and not on the whole thumbnail. I am trying to sort that out with html. But, you might have a solution with css only. Basicly in that context, how to put the text relative to a block which is a link. Sorry for my cheap code vocabulary.